# Imagemagick's -lat '50x50' not working in minimagick

Tags: ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, minimagick

I need to run local adaptive threshold(-lat) method in MiniMagick.

I tried with the following code:

`image.lat '50x50'`

Its give an error stack level too deep when image.write 'output.jpg' is run. 
[image: lat operator]

Can anyone suggest a way to use (-lat) method in MiniMagick.

Comment: That's odd - it doesn't seem to work at the command-line either... `mogrify -lat 5x5 fred.png mogrify: unrecognized option '-lat' error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/5256.`

Comment: @MarkSetchell `s/mogrify/convert/` would work for you.

Comment: Indeed! `convert` works when called like this `convert fred.png -lat 5x5 out.png`

Answer (score 0):

The common approach to stack options with `MiniMagick` is [`combine_options`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/probablycorey/mini_magick/MiniMagick/Image#combine_options-instance_method):

```
image.combine_options do |c|
  c.lat '50x50'
  # more options
end
```

This should not help in your case, though. `Image#write` copies the file from temporary location to the local file with given name. You might want to inspect your temporary file in `/var/folders/....` to see whether the threshold was applied.

It sounds like an imagemagick glitch. Did you try

```
$ mogrify -lat 50x50 file.jpg
```

Does it work?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Oh, indeed, copy-rethink-paste in-process :)

Comment: Morgify -lat 50x50 file.jpg gives an error :   mogrify: unrecognized option `-lat' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/5223.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `-lat` command is not included in `mogrify`. I ran into the same problem and found this question, two years after the OP, using IM version 6.9.2-3 Q16 x64 on Windows 7.

There is a discussion on the ImageMagick board [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=28647).